# flot graph not rendered on PDF using PDFKit

Tags: flot, pdfkit

I am using flot to generate graphs in my application. The graphs are rendered correctly. The web page is then converted to a pdf using PDFKit. On conversion, the coordinates[X,Y] of the graph are displayed correctly While the graph itself is not rendered.

Problem seems to be with the canvas tag-

```
<canvas class="base" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas class="overlay" width="600" height="300" style="position: absolute; left: 0px;   top: 0px;"></canvas>
```

Any clues on which direction to look to solve the problem will be very helpful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

PDFKit uses wkhtmltopdf to do the actual rendering right?  So you might need to dig into PDFKit and make sure it's specifying the right options for [wkhtmltopdf](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html), specifically `--redirect-delay <time>` might be useful.